# I have passed php date function inside my sql query to find results but my date function is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
enter code here<?php  public function totalExpense(){
    $todays = date('d-m-y');
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT SUM(amount) as value FROM price WHERE type='expense' AND time=".$todays;
    $sth = $this->dbh->query($sqlQuery);

    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $allData=  $sth->fetchAll();
    return $allData;
} ?>
```

But the date function does not returning today's value to database

Comment: What is the format for `time` column in database?

Comment: try putting it in single quotes in the query i.e. `time='".$todays."'"` ...but better still, learn how to use parameterised queries. Also, use a non-ambiguous format such as y-m-d. Right now if you pass today's date (11-05-2018) the DB might not know if you meant 11th May or 5th November - it could be d-m-y or m-d-y, mysql has no way to know your true intention.

Comment: time column format is varchar

Comment: "time column format is varchar"...so that's your next mistake. Never store dates and times as text. Dates/times are not text. Use the proper datetime column type. Then you can actually run queries against it and do things like sorting / filtering properly which you cannot do with mere string representation of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT SUM(amount) as value FROM price WHERE type='expense' AND time=".$todays;
```

Replace to

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT SUM(amount) as value FROM price WHERE type='expense' AND time='{$todays}'";
```

since time is varchar it should in **' or "**

Comment: @fahimhasan maybe it works for this specific case but it ignores all the flaws in your design pointed out in my comments and Jack's answer. In future you might have some new requirements. For instance,  try writing a query to find the total amount of expenses which occur after a given date...it is not possible using SQL (or at least not without a lot of unnecessary and inefficient on-the-fly conversion of strings to dates) because you cannot compare the date strings to each other properly to know which one is before or after the other. I'll repeat: Dates are not text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) as value FROM price WHERE type=:myType AND time=:myDate");
$query->bindParam(':myType', 'expense');
// Correct date format for MySql
$query->bindParam(':myDate', date('Y-m-d'));
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
```

This is the proper way to prepare a statement ( [take a look here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) ).
For MySql (from your tag) the correct format is Y-m-d.

**[Edited]**
Why it's "the proper way", from linked manual:

> - The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be    executed multiple times with the same or different parameters. When
>     the query is prepared, the database will analyze, compile and
>     optimize its plan for executing the query. For complex queries this
>     process can take up enough time that it will noticeably slow down an
>     application if there is a need to repeat the same query many times
>     with different parameters. By using a prepared statement the
>     application avoids repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This 
>     means that prepared statements use fewer resources and thus run
>     faster.
> - The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the    driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses 
>     prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection
>     will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built
>     up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Comment: yes...but you should add an explanation as well, otherwise OP will not understand _why_ this is correct. Then you'll get my upvote. Also note the recent comment that the date is stored as text in the DB...worth mentioning that needs correcting too